# rightMouseDown not called until button released

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I have an NSView subclass in which I need to detect left and right mouse down events. `mouseDown:` is working just fine, but `rightMouseDown:` doesn't fire until the mouse button has been released, at which point both the down and up methods are called in succession. How can I make the right mouse down event trigger its corresponding method immediately?

Comment: I'm curious what hardware you've got. I haven't had a mouse for ages. Many events are simulated. And some cannot be simulated without additional knowledge.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. In creating a minimal example I found the problem. I'll post an answer separately. I really should remember that you're supposed to start with the minimal situation when fixing a specific problem like this xD

Comment: Oh as for the hardware - it's an iMac and I'm using a Macig Trackpad 2

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have a `NSPanGestureRecognizer` added to the `NSView` with its `buttonMask` set to `0x2` (right mouse button). If I remove or disable this gesture recogniser, it allows `rightMouseDown:` to be called when the right button is pressed down. I'm still trying to figure out why, but at least now I have a starting point.